# How to Interactive Sort by Aggregate / Calculated Columns in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a stored procedure that return a detailed table with

```
agentid (varchar) , 
totalcalls (int) , 
talktime (int - seconds), 
holdtime (int - seconds)
```

For each hour.

So I have a SSRS tablix that sums totalcalls per agentid for a given period of time (parameters to the report)), sums talktime and holdtime too, and then I have two columns in the tablix that displays percentage of talktime (sum(talktime) / sum(talktime)/sum(holdtime)) and percentage of hold time (similar formula)

What I want to provide is for the user to sort by any of those percentage columns, so they can see who talks the most, the least, etc.

My question is, how do I Interactive Sort on those columns?

Thanks!

Comment: @Jeroen - I follow the standard procedure to configure interactive sort, but when I get to sort by, only actual fields are available to select from. I thought about adding a calculated field, but how do you do that with an aggregate? Or, is there such as thing as a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to table column header textbox(talktime) properties, click on "interactive Sorting" add sort expression as your required percentage formula "(sum(talktime) / sum(talktime)/sum(holdtime))" then click ok.. even you can add sorting to header "holdtime" text box with respective formula.

[image]