# SSRS 2008 Interactive sorting on matrix not working

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, matrix, ssrs-2008

I have a matrix report that returns the following fields: SupplierName, PurchasingCredit, AccDate, ColOrdr.  SupplierName list out rows, PurchasingCredit is the data value, AccDate is the column header, and ColOrder is just used to order the column headers on the report.  The report is usually about 150 rows by 16 columns.  Column headers include 13 individual months, Previous year-to-date, Current year-to-date, and Year-over-Year (YoY).

The report generates correctly, but the users would like to be able to use Interactive Sorting on two of the columns in the report: the SupplierName column (works fine) and YoY.  Nothing I have tried seems to allow me to sort based on this YoY column.  I get the sorting indicators, but clicking on them has no effect on the results whatsoever.

It looks as if this functionality just doesn't work within a matrix report.  Can someone please help me understand if this is the case or if not, just how such sorting may be accomplished?

Comment: What does the Interactive Sorting>"Sort By:" expression look like for the two columns in question?

Comment: I've tried several combinations.  After enabling interactive sorting (using checkbox), I have tried both Detail rows and groups.  I've tried using both matrix1_AccDate and matrix1_SupplierName as Groups.  Under the Sort By, I selected [PurchasingCredit] (my data value).  And I've tried the checkbox for Apply this sorting...  I made sure that sorting on SupplierName wasn't enabled on the column level.  No idea what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283102%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) seems to suggest that it is indeed possible. If there's one thing I've learned about SSRS, it's that it is finicky. Are you using a sort expression that renders the value you'd like to sort by? A similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496443/how-to-interactive-sort-by-aggregate-calculated-columns-in-ssrs-2008) suggests that a sorting expression is necessary. If the YoY column is being calculated by SQL, try replicating the formula using VB.NET in the Sorting expression. If the column is being calculated by SSRS, try copying the SSRS formula into the Sorting expression.

If the other Stack Overflow question helps you, be sure to vote it up.